# Unity WebGL build error in NON-development mode only

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

I'm using Unity 2017.3.03f free personal edition, I've an application in unity that works normally in desktop and android platforms. However, When it's built for WebGL release (**unchecked "development build" option"**) it gives this error in browser during loading splash screen:

```
> An error occurred running the Unity content on this page. See your browser JavaScript console for more info. The error was:
uncaught exception: abort(-1) at jsStackTrace (webgl-11B.asm.framework.unityweb:2:27460)
stackTrace (webgl-11B.asm.framework.unityweb:2:27631)
abort (webgl-11B.asm.framework.unityweb:4:33732)
_il2cpp_gc_disable (webgl-11B.asm.framework.unityweb:2:204426)
scripting_gc_disable() [vNc] (webgl-11B.asm.code.unityweb:10:1)
_main [eNc] (webgl-11B.asm.code.unityweb:10:1)
callMain (webgl-11B.asm.framework.unityweb:4:32097)
doRun (webgl-11B.asm.framework.unityweb:4:32800)
_String_Join_m2050845953 [run] (webgl-11B.asm.framework.unityweb:4:32986)
runCaller (webgl-11B.asm.framework.unityweb:4:31614)
removeRunDependency (webgl-11B.asm.framework.unityweb:2:34407)
processDataJob@file:.../Build/UnityLoader.js:1:17079
```

I've tried to **enable the development option** and apply the steps of this article:
https://community.gamedev.tv/t/webgl-debugging/54948

to *enable debugging symbols and disable stripping code engine to see the errors in browser console*. **But the Development version works without error**, but when I return to release build "unchecking the development option" again, the same error appears.

and the log of browser console contains the following message:

```
> IndexedDB is not available. Data will not persist in cache and PlayerPrefs will not be saved.
a2ab4d2b-6621-459b-b13f-f9b816ecb2f8:2:124
unreachable code after return statement[Learn More]
a2ab4d2b-6621-459b-b13f-f9b816ecb2f8:2:4519
missing function: il2cpp_gc_disable
UnityLoader.js:1:8039
-1
UnityLoader.js:1:8002
-1
UnityLoader.js:1:8039
Use of the motion sensor is deprecated.
a2ab4d2b-6621-459b-b13f-f9b816ecb2f8:2:54097
Use of the orientation sensor is deprecated.
a2ab4d2b-6621-459b-b13f-f9b816ecb2f8:2:54097
uncaught exception: abort(-1) at jsStackTrace@blob:null/a2ab4d2b-6621-459b-b13f-f9b816ecb2f8:2:27460
stackTrace@blob:null/a2ab4d2b-6621-459b-b13f-f9b816ecb2f8:2:27631
abort@blob:null/a2ab4d2b-6621-459b-b13f-f9b816ecb2f8:4:33732
_il2cpp_gc_disable@blob:null/a2ab4d2b-6621-459b-b13f-f9b816ecb2f8:2:204426
vNc@blob:null/036e0461-a7f5-4bf6-9bcd-65ad983ad95c:10:1
eNc@blob:null/036e0461-a7f5-4bf6-9bcd-65ad983ad95c:10:1
callMain@blob:null/a2ab4d2b-6621-459b-b13f-f9b816ecb2f8:4:32097
doRun@blob:null/a2ab4d2b-6621-459b-b13f-f9b816ecb2f8:4:32800
run@blob:null/a2ab4d2b-6621-459b-b13f-f9b816ecb2f8:4:32986
runCaller@blob:null/a2ab4d2b-6621-459b-b13f-f9b816ecb2f8:4:31614
removeRunDependency@blob:null/a2ab4d2b-6621-459b-b13f-f9b816ecb2f8:2:34407
processDataJob.../UnityLoader.js:1:17079
If this abort() is unexpected, build with -s ASSERTIONS=1 which can give more information.
154
UnityLoader.js:1:8002
154
UnityLoader.js:1:8039
uncaught exception: abort(154) at jsStackTrace@blob:null/a2ab4d2b-6621-459b-b13f-f9b816ecb2f8:2:27460
stackTrace@blob:null/a2ab4d2b-6621-459b-b13f-f9b816ecb2f8:2:27631
abort@blob:null/a2ab4d2b-6621-459b-b13f-f9b816ecb2f8:4:33732
Vxq@blob:null/036e0461-a7f5-4bf6-9bcd-65ad983ad95c:32:1
y7c@blob:null/036e0461-a7f5-4bf6-9bcd-65ad983ad95c:23:1
ynq@blob:null/036e0461-a7f5-4bf6-9bcd-65ad983ad95c:32:1
handlerFunc@blob:null/a2ab4d2b-6621-459b-b13f-f9b816ecb2f8:2:57395
jsEventHandler@blob:null/a2ab4d2b-6621-459b-b13f-f9b816ecb2f8:2:53935
```

why does this error happen? is it because of **using unity free edition**, or because the **application reads some text file from Resources folder** at loading?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Every browser, or just Chrome?

Comment: I've tested it on firefox, Edge, and Opera , same error.

Comment: Do you use the default wegbl template? Do you use 3rd party assets? What are your scripting backend and framework settings? Have you tried export all and import into a clean new project?